# Gazebo simulation GPS fix

Tags: ros, gazebo7

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am getting warning [warn] FP: NO GPS FIX while running the gazebo simulation for the ground rover. I am trying to move the rover based on the input waypoint lists. However, I cannot get the GPS fix data for the rover in simulation. How can I fix this problem? Any helps will be appreciated! I am using the Erlerobot's rover model and ardupilot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258307/gazebo-simulation-gps-fix/) by [cho](https://answers.ros.org/users/29881/cho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) on 2017-04-03**:
Did you try `rostopic list`, to see, whether your model publishes any GPS data?

**Comment by [cho](https://answers.ros.org/users/29881/cho/) on 2017-04-05**:
Yes I did. And it was publishing the gps data but it just keep showing the same value even if the rover starts to travel. Sorry for the late reply

**Comment by [moshimojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30028/moshimojo/) on 2018-01-30**:
Hi! Did you find any solution? Does it need a map of the environment first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could not find out quickly, how the rover model from Erlerobot generates GPS data, but you could try to use the simulated GPS device from [hector_gazebo_plugins](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_gazebo_plugins) instead. That one works pretty well.

To install hector_gazebo_plugins use:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-DISTRIBUTION-hector-gazebo-plugins
```

Afterwards add the following lines inside your `<robot><gazebo> </gazebo></robot>` tags of your URDF file (or `<model> </model>`, if you are using SDF):

```
<plugin name="gps_controller" filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_gps.so">
    <alwayson>true</alwayson>
    <updaterate>1.0</updaterate>
    <bodyname>base_link</bodyname>
    <topicname>/fix</topicname>
    <velocitytopicname>/fix_velocity</velocitytopicname>
    <drift>5.0 5.0 5.0</drift>
    <gaussiannoise>0.1 0.1 0.1</gaussiannoise>
    <velocitydrift>0 0 0</velocitydrift>
    <velocitygaussiannoise>0.1 0.1 0.1</velocitygaussiannoise>
</plugin>
```

The hector plugin above generates [sensor_msgs/NavSatFix](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/NavSatFix.html) messages. If ardupilot really requires [gps_common/GPSFix](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/gps_common/html/msg/GPSFix.html) messages, you can use the *fix_translator* script in the [gps_common](http://wiki.ros.org/gps_common) package to do the conversion. The best way to use the translator ist to adapt the *fix_tanslator.launch* file to the topic names on your system.

---

Originally posted by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) with karma: 775 on 2017-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0